# Не работает нажатие на созданный элемент js

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, reactjs

После отправки post запроса на сервере создается элемент, затем я получаю его и создаю его в html, но при клике на него не открывается модальное окно, но при этом у всех изначальных элементов открывается

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/form_style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/workspace.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/project.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="workspace_user_info">
                <div class="workspace_username">
                    {{ request.user.username }} -
                    <span class="workspace_user_status">{{ context.type }}</span>
                </div>
                {% if request.user.privilege %}
                    <div class="workspace_user_rank">
                        {{ context.privilege }}
                    </div>
                {% elif request.user.rank %}
                    <div class="workspace_user_rank">
                        {{ request.user.rank }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="category_container">
        <div class="category_items">
            {% for i in context.objects %}
                <div class="category_items_container">
                    <div class="category_object" id="{{ i.id }}">{{ i.title }}</div>
                    <div class="category_modal">
                        <button class="category_edit" value="{{ i.id }}">Edit</button>
                        <form class="category_edit_form">
                            <input type="text" value="{{ i.title }}" class="update_date">
                            <button class="category_edit_button" type="button">Edit</button>
                        </form>
                        <button class="category_delete" value="{{ i.id }}">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="models_classes">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="category_create">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="category_title">Создать категорию:</div>
                <div>{{ form.title }}</div>
                <button class="category_button">Создать</button>
            </form>
            <div class="models_title">Меню быстрого доступа:</div>
            <a href="{% url 'workspace' %}">проекты</a>
            <a href="{% url 'management' %}">менеджмент</a>
            <a href="{% url 'object_permissions' %}">резрешения для проектов</a>
            <a href="{% url 'project_members' %}">разрешения для категорий</a>
            <a href="{% url 'users_list' %}">пользователи</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="{% static 'js/category.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
       let post_button = document.querySelector('.category_button')
       let csrftoken = '{% csrf_token %}'
       let container = document.querySelector('.category_items')
       let objects = document.querySelectorAll('.category_object')
       let edit = document.querySelectorAll('.category_edit')
       let edit_button = document.querySelectorAll('.category_edit_button')
       let delete_button = document.querySelectorAll('.category_delete')

       refreshToken('/api/token/refresh/', {
                "refresh": localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')
           }).then((data) => {
           localStorage.setItem('token', data.access)
       })

       post_button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
           e.preventDefault()
           let inp = document.querySelector('.project_input')
           postData('/api/category', {
               "title": inp.value
           }, localStorage.getItem('token')).then(() =>{
                getData('/api/category', localStorage.getItem('token')).then((data) =>{
                    let get_data = data[data.length - 1]
                    console.log(get_data)
                    const newRow = document.createElement('div');
                    newRow.innerHTML =
                        `
                            <div class="category_object" id="${get_data.id}">${get_data.title}</div>
                            <div class="category_modal" >
                                <button class="category_edit" value="${ get_data.id }">Edit</button>
                                <form class="category_edit_form">
                                    <input type="text" value="${ get_data.title }" class="update_date">
                                    <button class="category_edit_button" type="button">Edit</button>
                                </form>
                                <button class="category_delete" value="${ get_data.id }">Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        `
                    newRow.classList = 'category_items_container'
                    container.append(newRow, container.firstChild);
                    document.querySelector('.category_create').reset();
                })
           })
        })

       edit_button.forEach((e) =>{
            e.addEventListener('click', (item) =>{
            item.preventDefault()
            let del_button = e.parentElement.nextElementSibling
            let edit_button = e.parentElement.previousElementSibling
            let modal_form = e.parentElement.parentElement
            let formInput = e.previousElementSibling.value
            let object = document.getElementById(edit_button.value)
            updateData(`/api/category/${edit_button.value}`, {
                "id": `${edit_button.value}`,
                "title": `${formInput}`
            }).then((data) => {
                object.textContent = data.title
            })

            if (modal_form.style.display === 'flex'){
                modal_form.style.display = 'none'
                e.parentElement.style.display = 'none'
                edit_button.style.display = 'block'
                del_button.style.display = 'block'
            } else{
                modal_form.style.display = 'flex'
                edit_button.style.display = 'none'
                del_button.style.display = 'none'
            }
        })
    })

    delete_button.forEach((e) =>{
        e.addEventListener('click', (item) =>{
        item.preventDefault()
        let object = document.getElementById(e.value)
        deleteData(`/api/category/${e.value}`, localStorage.getItem('token'))
        object.parentElement.style.display = 'none'
    })})

    document.querySelectorAll('.category_object').forEach((e) =>{
    e.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        if (e.nextElementSibling.style.display === 'flex'){
            e.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none'
        } else{
            e.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'flex'
        }
        })
    })
    edit.forEach((e) =>{
        e.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            let del_button = e.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling
            if (e.nextElementSibling.style.display === 'flex'){
                e.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none'
                e.style.display = 'block'
                del_button.style.display = 'block'
            } else{
                e.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'flex'
                e.style.display = 'none'
                del_button.style.display = 'none'
            }
        })
    })

async function updateData(url = "", data = {}) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    return await response.json();
}
async function deleteData(url = "", token) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `token ${token}`
        },
    });
    return await response.json();
}
async function postData(url = "", data = {}, token) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `token ${token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    return await response.json();
}
async function getData(url = "", token) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `token ${token}`
        },
    });
    return await response.json();
}
async function refreshToken(url = "", data = {}) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    return await response.json();
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Потому что слушатели событий на новые элементы не устанавливаются. Скрипт по созданию слушателей отрабатывает один раз. В том месте, где вы создаете новые элементы, создавайте для них слушатели.

Comment: @SwaD но разве функция не должна сработать если классы одинаковые?

Comment: Нет. Она отработала и все. Те элементы, что были в момент работы функции, получили слушатели. Новые нет.

Comment: @SwaD спасибо, сработало!